# Stored Procedure AddDate function and validation errors

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure and testing some basic concepts.

For the last few hours, I am getting errors with this procedure, in terms of syntax. This is in MySQL (MariaDB).

```
use fifteens
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE TestProcedure() (INOUT :startDate, :count)
   BEGIN
DECLARE x INT default 0; 
REPEAT
 SELECT DATE_ADD(startDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
   SET x = x + 1; 
        UNTIL x  = count;
        END REPEAT;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Any help in resolving this would help me get to the next level :)

Comment: Server will never use the syntax you invented. Remove colons from argument list. Add semicolon to SELECT and remove from UNTIL.

Comment: Remove the `()`.  RTFM

Comment: I figured the errors here. The ':' are not correct for sql, my reference source was wrong. Besides this, there were many others errors, as i have learnt to write it correctly. I will post the better way to do this soon